# Get hardware info on Android?

Tags: android, hardware

In adb shell, do we have any command to get device info, like lspci?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be on android.stackexchange.com, but anyhow. even if you are not rooted, you can access use `getprop` and it will return information about the device.

Comment: Thanks for the info. getprop is good but it doesn't provide enough vendor information as lspci does.

Comment: This shouldn't have been selected as the answer. getprop is not an alternative to lspci.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid access to the linux layer is only possible by "rooting" the device

Comment: Not true. You can adb shell just fine into an un-rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some (messy) messages from dmesg:

```
$ adb shell dmesg
```

Note that the kernel ring buffer is limited. The first few lines may be dropped as time goes by.

dmesg requires root, too.